# Power BI Finding the Average of a Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am attempting to create a measure YTD % Price Change.

In the below extract I would like to get the YTD average ( or total ) for both columns and divide them. ( Sum of CY GRPi / Sum of LY GRPi )

Current Attempt;

```
DIVIDE(CALCULATE('Measures tbl'[CY Net GRPi], all('Fact PMA'[Calendar Year/Month.Calendar Year/Month Level 01.Key])), CALCULATE('Measures tbl'[LY Net GRPi], all('Fact PMA'[Calendar Year/Month.Calendar Year/Month Level 01.Key])))
```

CY Net GRPi and LY Net GRPi are themselves a culmination of several different measures.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Show your sample raw data and then your expected output from them.

Comment: INPUTS = (82,46% + 80,57%) / (80,77% +76,99%) = 81,5166 %